# How does Address Locator pick one of two alternative points in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding, network, address

I have geo coded the main entrance of buildings on my map and some buildings have more than one entrance. How does address locator pick one of them?

To me it seems it is just randomly picking one of say the three points with the same address.

I am using this data on a network and for routing purposes, I need to guide people to the main entrances and snap them on the network.

Comment: Address locators vary on how they locate points depending on how they are set up - are you using a specific one? Does 'random' mean the selected point can or does change each time you locate the same address? Or does it always select the same point of the available options? If so, is that point the closest to the 'true' location (ie, linear reference point along the street segment based on the to-from address range)? Have you reviewed the Geocoding [help files](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_geocoding/002500000001000000/), particularly those on locators?

Comment: Thank you. I did several tests and apparently it selects the leftmost point all the time and no it is not the closest point to street segment. I manually geocoded the points,it is not based on to-from address range. Thank you again

Comment: Without seeing an image example it's hard to say if that's actually what's going on. It may be selecting the first matching record based on address, and if they were always created left to right... Geocoding the *points* is a bit different than using a locator to *select* one. Closest to the street doesn't matter as much as where *along* the street it lies.