# Geocoding building with different entrances?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding, network-analyst, reverse-geocoding

I am working on a routing map for a university campus. the routes are modeled and network analyst works fine.

The problem: Many of these buildings have several entrances.

Is there a way to geocode all of them and have network analyst understand which entrance is most suitable or do I have to geocode them with different names?

I ran a test and it seems, the address locator always picks the leftmost entrance with the similar name.

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114493/  I'm pretty sure you wouldn't be able to do this unless you have a specific point for a given entrance *and* that entrance is specified. See the related question as far as issues with how an address locator picks, but a network analysis is going to have different factors - ie arrival on right side of the street, u-turns allowed, which direction the route comes from, etc. Network isn't going to pick a point from choices, it's going to go to the specified point.

Answer (score 1):

I would instead of trying to geocode to the entrances, have a related featureclass with entrance points for each building. If Building A has entrances X, Y, and Z, allow the geocode to building A, then based on the result, use the relation, route to all three entrances, and pick the one with the most favorable outcome: shortest distance, shortest travel time, fewest turns.... etc

Unfortunately I see the potential for this to increase lag time in showing the 'answer' route...